# I use HT condor for running python script for image preprocessing using cv2 but received error saying that no module named cv2

Tags: python, opencv, htcondor

I am trying to run [ython script on image preprocessing using cv2 library. I have run the job submit.
I received error from log file : `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/lib/condor/execute/dir_4744/image.py", line 4, in <module> import cv2 as cv ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'` .

After submit the job. I have pip install opencv-python. But still face this error. I also try to restart and do it again. Still facing this issue.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)